# what is the difference between these 2 sql statements

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
select s.id,s.name,e.sem from student as s, enroll as e where s.id = e.id;

select s.id,s.name,e.sem from student join enroll using (id);
```

so these 2 statements get the same result, but what is the difference? is there any case where they are not the same?

Comment: nothing. They resolve to the same thing. The first is old-style joins in a where clause. Yuck. The second is the short form of modern joining .... the second one saves your from typing `on student.id=enroll.id`

Comment: `s.id = e.id` is the same thing which `join` here does . Difference is the style of the query executed . As @Drew said , First one is old style the another saves some bit of finger pain :D :p

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: There are small differences between the two but they are not significant. A well-written program should not depend on these differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are the same thing, one is the old style while the other saves some time and typing.